Why and how can @Entity be used with enum types?
I started by wanting to get rid of an ERole enum type that my TA used to enumerate some roles that users can have. It looks like this:
public enum ERole {
    CUSTOMER,
    MANAGER,
    ADMIN
}

Because we're learning spring boot, the way that my TA persisted these Roles in a database was like this:
@Entity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Integer id;

    @Enumerated( EnumType.STRING )
    @Column( length = 20 )
    private ERole name;
}

The "role" table is needed because a user can have multiple roles. A many-to-many relationship between the "user" and "role" tables is used.
@Entity
@Table ( uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint ( columnNames = { "username", "email" } ) } )
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue ( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Long id;

    @Column ( nullable = false, length = 20 )
    private String username;

    @Column ( nullable = false, length = 50 )
    private String email;

    @Column ( nullable = false, length = 120 )
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany ( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinTable ( name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn ( name = "user_id" ),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn ( name = "role_id" ) )
    private Set <Role> roles = new HashSet <> ( );
}

My goals are the following:

Have just one Role enum/class where I can define my Role types
Have a "role" table be automatically created
Have these Role types be automatically inserted into the "role" table with an automatically generated and unique ID
Be able to create a JpaRepository for my Role enum/class

So far I've managed to come up with the following:
@Entity
public enum MyRole {
    CUSTOMER,
    MANAGER,
    ADMIN;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue ( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Integer id;
}

and MyRoleRepository, which looks like this:
public interface MyRoleRepository extends JpaRepository <MyRole, Integer> {
}

But I am getting this error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myRoleRepository' defined in org.example.springskeleton.user.MyRoleRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.lang.Enum.name accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @4988d8b8

From what I've searched through documentation (@Entity, @Target, ElementType), I understand that @Entity can be used with enum types, according to its @Target annotation, but so far I have not found any examples of how that is intended to be done.
In essence, I think I have two questions:

Is there a better way of doing what my TA was trying to do?
If so, is my idea of having an enum Entity a better way/even possible?

This is my first SO question, so I'm sorry if I've done anything incorrectly. Thanks for the help!

The concept of enums and a database table are contrary to each other. Either we make ERole a normal class, or we save the list of roles in a different way, e.g. in an array.

It doesn't make sense to map an enum as an @Entity because enum are types with static values that are initialized when the enum is loaded. You can't load new values to the enum at runtime. That's not the way you must do it.
One way you can implement what you need is to have the User entity, the Role entity and a Roles enum. This enum would have all the role values that you have in your roles table, and also it would have an attribute for the database id of the role. This is very important because you need to know the id of each role of the enum when you start your application. This way you can associate the enum values with the Role entity values. You can also add other attributes to the Roles enum (i.e. the description of the role).
public enum Roles {
    CUSTOMER(1L),
    MANAGER(2L),
    ADMIN(3L);

    private Long id;

    private Roles(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

The Role entity must be mapped with all the fields of the database (id, name, etc.). You don't need to map an additional field with the enum value. With this approach, you must remove the automatic id generation from the Role entity. If you want to use a enum for the roles, it's supposed that the role values of the database will not change frequently in the future. And also you need to know the id of the role when you declare the value in the enum, so you don't need the automatic id generation.
public class Role {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column( length = 20 )
    private String name;
} 

The User entity will be mostly the same. You can add some @Transient methods that can help you with the role checking, or have a service class with utility methods that help you handle the role operations. For example, you can add a method that checks if a user has a role using the enum:
@Transient
public boolean hasRole(Roles role) {
    return roles.stream().anyMatch(r -> r.getId().equals(role.getId());
}

You can have a service method that adds a enum role to a user, hiding the internal use of the Role class:
public void addRoleToUser(Roles role, User user) {
    Role roleToAdd = roleRepository.findById(role.getId());
    user.getRoles().add(roleToAdd);
}

